# Help to identify an SMD SOD-123 diode

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount

I need to replace a diode on heavily damaged board.  Unfortunately, I don't have any schematics. It is an SOD-123 package (I measured it and it is around 3.6 mm width.)

Is there a way to identify it?

Sorry for the image quality, I hope is enough to identify the component.

[image]

Comment: I hope that damage was caused mechanically, otherwise the fault that lead to this is probably still there and replacing the diode might not be sufficient

Comment: Yes.. unfortunately the damage was a mechanical one…an human error on mounting the board on the main system

Comment: that's good! if it was electrical, you'd probably have a problem elsewhere, too. Anyway, context for identification is usually helpful: can you show what components are around this? Maybe even reverse-engineer the schematic a bit?

Comment: Can you still measure it's forward voltage to determine if it's a schottky? Perhaps this is some manufacturer's marking for the popular SS14.

Comment: Why is your image mirrored? Surely you can take a better picture than this and, if you took it originally, how did you manage to mirror it?

Comment: @Andyaka Is a low quality microscope picture i don't notice that was mirrored.... Sorry I dont' understand that this can be a problem! I will try to take a better picture

Comment: The problem is that you expect people to freely help with bad information and sloppiness. One thing I can tell you about EE (and all engineering disciplines) is that total attention to detail is paramount; in fact it's a way of life.

Comment: @Andyaka yes, I understand your point, I'm truly sorry for my error, I will try to do my best with my limited resources. Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: @Unimportant thank you for your suggestion, I will try to measure as you suggested and back with result

Answer (score 4):

Possibly [40V 1A Schottky diode](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/LESH/LESH-S-A0000132232/LESH-S-A0000132232-1.pdf?hkey=52A5661711E402568146F3353EA87419).

Photo from LCSC.com: [image]